# NSOutlineView expand childs

Tags: swift, macos, nsoutlineview

I have an NSOutlineView where I'm trying to implement "search & replace" ability but the problem is that all nodes are not getting expanding.

```
let nodes : [NSTreeNode] = self.getNode(contains: "any word")

for node in nodes {
  self.outlineView.expandItem(node.parent) // that only work for short index path

  let row = self.outline.row(forItem: item)
    if row >= 0 {
      self.outlineView.scrollRowToVisible(row)
      self.outlineView.selectRowIndexes(IndexSet(integer: row), byExtendingSelection: false)
    }
}
```

The problem is that nodes at certain level doesn't get expanded. 
How can I start expanding NSTreenode(s) starting from the initial parent node to the last child parent that contains my search?

Comment: How about using recursion?

Comment: How about iterating over `node.indexPath`?

Comment: Hi matt, yes recursion, but recursion of the parent?

Comment: Hi Willeke, I can make it work this way: func asyncExpand(item: NSTreeNode?, expandParentOnly: Bool) {
    var parents : [NSTreeNode] = [NSTreeNode]()
    var parent : NSTreeNode? = item?.parent
    repeat {
      if (parent != nil) {
        parents.insert(parent!, at: 0)
      }
      
      parent = parent?.parent
    } while parent != nil
    
    for n in parents {
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.outline.expandItem(n)
      }
    }
    
    if !expandParentOnly {
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.outline.expandItem(item)
      }
    }
  }

Comment: Please show me a possible recursion using IndexPath

Comment: I need the lighter way as possible as I have problems with tens of thousands of nodes

Comment: How about starting from the child and expanding the parents? Out of curiosity, how do you find the `NSTreeNode`s in `self.getNode(contains: "any word")`?

Comment: Hi Willeke, doing the reverse doesn't work, in fact only works for index set like [0, 1] but not for [0, 1, 5]. getNode(contains:) is it very fast, if that is your curiosity, because nothing related to views. It calls other method that iterate childrens recursively (by calling itself for each children) and just add nodes  that match (e.g. those have a "key" or a value that mach the string partially and ignoring the case)  to an array. Also those nodes are added in order as in the ouline rows order.. so tha I can navigate through them by using a segmented control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursion, expand the parent before expanding the node:

```
func expandNode(_ node:NSTreeNode) {
    if let parent = node.parent {
        if !outlineView.isItemExpanded(parent) {
            self.expandNode(parent)
        }
    }
    outlineView.expandItem(node)
}

self.expandNode(node)
```

Iterating over `node.indexPath`:

```
var treeNode = treeController.arrangedObjects
node.indexPath.forEach { index in
    treeNode = treeNode.children![index]
    if !outlineView.isItemExpanded(treeNode) {
        outlineView.expandItem(treeNode)
    }
}
```